# Repercussions of setting the IIS responseBufferLimit to = 0

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

I'm running a PHP application (Moodle) under FastCGI in IIS 8.5, Windows Server 2012 R2 and PHP 5.4. There are two VM server nodes in the setup using an F5 load balancer. I am using Wincache for the File System and User caches and OPCache for the Opcode cache. The application writes to a MSSQL database using the Microsoft PHP SQLSRV drivers.

I'm trying to resolve some slow reponse issues we are getting when the site is busy. We get about 600 visitors per day.

One of the things that my research turned up is to set the **responseBufferLimit** setting to 0. But what isn't really explained anywhere is what the repercussions of doing that are.

Are there any reasons NOT to set it to 0? What are the consequences of setting it to 0?

If 0 isn't a good idea, how do I determine what the correct value should be?

(Yes, I am fully aware that 5.4 is an old version of PHP.)

Comment: PHP 5.4 has expired for years. If you really want to improve performance, use latest PHP 7.x, which is well known for massive performance improvements. Then you can ignore less useful tips like tuning some parameters you don't know.

Comment: Thanks. I would still have asked this question if I was running PHP 7. I want to know what the repercussions of setting the IIS responseBufferLimit to = 0 are, regardless of what version of PHP I am, or should be, running.

Comment: There are reasons people are still using older versions of PHP and upgrading is not always so simple.  If you have thousands of references to mysql_query which all need to be upgraded to PDO before you can upgrade your version of PHP for example, that's a big job.